# Dealing with time data, how do I convert this AS3 line to Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an old line of code for an AS3 application:

```
return Math.Round((DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1,1)).TotalMilliseconds);
```

However, I'm currently working in Javascript / Typescript. I tried to write what felt like a conversion, but it's just producing NaN.

```
getTime() {
    return Math.round((new Date().Now - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
}
```

How can I fix this small snippet so that it produces the same results?

Comment: new Date().now() ?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, it's as simple as this:

```
new Date().getTime() // For Milliseconds

Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) // For Seconds
```

`.getTime()` returns the milliseconds since the epoch of January 1, 1970 UTC.  To convert that to seconds, divide by 1,000.  And, the `Math.round()` to get you seconds instead of milliseconds.

So, you were almost there, it's just that `new Date().Now` isn't a thing.  :-)

Comment: Thank you - I saw this a couple of times, but it felt too simple. I was tricking myself into making it more complicated.